# Create html select with optgroup from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON string (from php json_encode) that looks like;

```
var json = [{"Foo":[{"id":1,"name":"aaa"},{"id":2,"name":"bbb"}]},{"Bar":[{"id":3,"name":"ccc"},{"id":4,"name":"ddd"}]}];
```

I want to be able to create an html select using Javascript/jQuery in the form;

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Foo">
        <option value="1">aaa</option>
        <option value="2">bbb</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Bar">
        <option value="3">ccc</option>
        <option value="4">ddd</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

In terms of processing the json I get [this far](http://jsfiddle.net/DVKMK/) (not far I know), but jsFiddle fails to run it and freezes my browser.

```
var json = [{"Foo":[{"id":1,"name":"aaa"},{"id":2,"name":"bbb"}]},{"Bar":[{"id":3,"name":"ccc"},{"id":4,"name":"ddd"}]}];

$.each(json, function(i,group) {
    console.log(i);
    $.each(group, function(j, option) {
        console.log(j, option);
        $.each(option, function(k, item) {
            console.log(k, item);
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Set your fiddle to use jQuery instead of MooTools, and it seems to run just fine http://jsfiddle.net/DVKMK/1/

Comment: He is trying to dynamically create the <selects>, his JS doesn't do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should run just fine.

```
var $select = $("<select>");
$select.appendTo("#somewhere");

$.each(json, function(i, optgroups) {
    $.each(optgroups, function(groupName, options) {
        var $optgroup = $("<optgroup>", {label: groupName});
        $optgroup.appendTo($select);

        $.each(options, function(j, option) {
            var $option = $("<option>", {text: option.name, value: option.id});
            $option.appendTo($optgroup);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You want `var $select = $("<select>");` outside of the each  or it will create one for each group. http://jsfiddle.net/DVKMK/3/

Comment: @webnoob absolutely. Thanks for the hint.