# Adding <optgroup> dynamically from javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This may seem a cack-handed way of doing things, but I'm experimenting with this.

I have a list of UK counties, and a list of US states. When the user selects "UK" or "US" from the dropdown, it repopulates the second select list. (I DID get this to work by submitting the form each time the select options were changed, and rebuilding the HTML form ... but realised that was a somewhat server intensive mode, so now want to do it via Javascript)

I began by reading the text file into a javascript array, (actually, a PERL script reads the file, turns it into code, and then prints out the HTML) So I end up with:

```
var state_opt = new Array('1','2','3','4',' ...
var state_title = new Array('Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Arkansas' ...
```

I then use a loop to load the second array:

```
for (x=0; x<state_opt.length; x++){
document.userChoice.c_s.options[x]=new Option(state_title[x],state_opt[x])
}
```

That works fine ... until I try the second array which features <optgroup></optgroup> The above loop automatically makes them into options!! Here are the arrays:

```
var county_opt = new Array('-','2','3','4', ...
var county_title = new Array('<optgroup label="England">','Bedfordshire','Berkshire','Bristol' ...
```

** Notice I have made the <optgroup> value into "-" so it can be distinguished. (When writing in PERL, this is the concept I used:

```
If ($county_opt[$x] eq "-"){
$option.=$county_title[$x];
}
else{
$option.="<option value=\"$county_opt[$x]\">$country_title[$x]";
}
```

And then write "<select>$option</select>

So what I'm seeking is code something like this:

```
for (x=0; x<county_opt.length; x++){
        var str=county_title[x];
            if (str.match(/optgroup/g)){ 
        // ??   document.userChoice.c_s.options[x]=county_title[x];
        // ie print the value as is without making it into an option
            }
            else{
            document.userChoice.c_s.options[x]=new Option(county_title[x],county_opt[x])
            }
        }
```

Any SIMPLE ideas? If it can't be done, I'll just have to remove the labels

Comment: With your javascript code, you could dynamically generate your select a bit differently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956667/create-html-select-with-optgroup-from-json

Comment: Just checked the link you gave, but that uses the javascript that uses the "$" (JSON?) That's a whole new programming concept for me. I'm still getting to grips with the 'old fashioned' version

Comment: that's the jQuery library semantics

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm ... that was a 'challenging' morning! The solution might be technically wrong in parts ... but it works.

I found a way to add the  tags without making them into selectable options, but *because* they were not options, when changing to another option list, I could not remove these <optgroup> tags by using a loop that removed option elements!! (Does that make sense?)

Instead, the crude way I ended up doing it was to use innerHTML to set the text within the <select> form option to null. I then (incorrectly?) created a string built up with ≤optgroup><option> tags and values, and used innerHTML to replace it again

The "ind2" other option is the (correct) way to replace all option fields.

Hope this helps someone.

Incidentally, you'll also notice the "Not Available" have values of "-". Quite simply, if the user selects this option, an error trap routine sees these values, and simply returns to the form with a false value.

```
function checkCountry(){
document.userChoice.c_s.innerHTML=''
var ind=document.userChoice.countryChoice.selectedIndex;   
// set 1 for UK, 2 for US
//'Please select a Country' has an option value of '0'

    if (ind == 0){  // resets 2nd / 3rd option list if don't select US or UK 
    document.userChoice.c_s.options[0]=new Option("NOT AVAILABLE","-");
    document.userChoice.service.options[0]=new Option("NOT AVAILABLE","-");
    }

    if (ind == 1){
    var t='<option value="-">Please select a County</option>';
    for (x=0; x<county_opt.length; x++){
    var str=county_opt[x];
        if (str.match(/-/)){ 
        t+=county_title[x]; // Sets the <optgroup> tag with no option value
        }
        else{
        t+='<option value="'+county_opt[x]+'">'+county_title[x];
        }
    }
    document.userChoice.c_s.innerHTML=t;
    }

    if (ind == 2){   // preferred method that won't remove <optgroup> from <select> area
    document.userChoice.c_s.options[0]=new Option('Please select a State','-');
        for (x=1; x<state_opt.length; x++){
        document.userChoice.c_s.options[x]=new Option(state_title[x],state_opt[x])
        }
    }
}
</script>
```